# How to set size of hidden state vector in LSTM, keras?

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I am currently setting the vector size by using `model.add(LSTM(50))` i.e setting the value in `units` attribute but I highly doubt its correctness(In keras documentation, units is explained as dimensionality of the output space). Anyone who can help me here?

Answer (score 0):

If by vector size you mean the number of nodes in a layer, then yes you are doing it right. The output dimensionality of your layer 
is the same as the number of nodes. The same thing applies to convolutional layers, number of filters and output dimensionality along the last axis, aka number of color channels is the same.

Comment: The output is either a 0 or a 1 whereas the hidden state vector's size is 50.

Comment: Wait a second, what is your output layer and what is you input shap?